# Como salvar a id de um relativeLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout

Olá, boa tarde. Sou novo em programação Android e não estou conseguindo salvar a ID de um relativeLayout para ser comparado.

Exemplo:

```
 <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/idAmc"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="65dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:background="@drawable/shadow_grey"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:onClick="selecionaMenuTec">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/ic_amc"
            android:layout_width="40dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_amc" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/amc"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/amc"
            android:textAlignment="center" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/empresaAmc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:layout_marginStart="12dp"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/ic_amc"
            android:text="ABC Empresa"
            android:textAppearance="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Body2"
            android:textSize="15sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mediaAmc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@+id/empresaAmc"
            android:layout_marginLeft="180dp"
            android:text="@string/media" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/mediaValorAmc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text="0%"
            android:textSize="25sp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/mediaAmc" />


    </RelativeLayout>
```

Como faço para pegar o ID desse relativeLayout e salvar em uma variável para futura comparação?

Já tentei utilizar o findViewById() mas não de certo.

Quero fazer algo do tipo: `

```
public class menuTec extends AppCompatActivity{

public void selecionaMenuTec(RelativeLayout view)
{
    RelativeLayout layoutMenuTec = view;



    if( view == R.id.idAmc){



    }

}
```

}

Comment: Você quer receber esse valor: idAmc?

Comment: Vc está em um Fragment?

Comment: Quero receber esse idAmc. A ideia é verificar esse idAMc em um if. E chamar um fragment. @Luc

Comment: Quero receber esse idAmc. A ideia é verificar esse idAMc em um if. E chamar um fragment @LeonardoDias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O seu código não está funcionando porque você está comparando uma `View` com um **inteiro**.

O correto seria pegar o **Id** da **view** que o método recebe como parâmetro, assim:

```
public void selecionaMenuTec(View view){
    if (view.getId() == R.id.idAmc) {
        // faça alguma coisa
    }  
}
```

Comment: Entendi, eu fiz um relativeLayout clicavél, quando o usuário clicar nele vai abrir um fragment. Como que eu pego a id desse layout e compraro ela com outras? Na minha função selecionaMenuTec () quero receber esse layout, depois pegar o id desse layout e salvar em uma variavel para ser comprada com os outros ids, para ver qual fragment abrir. @Luc

Comment: Editei a resposta

Comment: Isso eu fiz direto no XML  android:onClick="selecionaMenuTec". Meu problema é quero salvar a id desse layout. Edeitei minha pergunta. @Luc

Comment: Mude o parâmetro RelativeLayout para View.

Comment: Editado de acordo com  tua pergunta, já que a resposta anterior não era relacionado com o que você quer.

Comment: Muio obrigado @Luc